# Layout is wrong - Chrome vs IOS Simulator

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Here is what I have in sencha architect and IOS simulator :

[image: IOS/Sencha Architect]

It's nice and exactly what I want.

Here is what I get in Chrome

[image: Chrome]

What happened to the textfields? They are completely messed up. Width is wrong, each field takes 2 rows, editable field is not even Right of the label, it is kind of under it.

Does anyone understand and can help me resolve this issue?

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('CarboZero.view.EditPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.ActionSheet',

    requires: [
        'CarboZero.view.DatePicker'
    ],

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                itemId: 'hbox_Container',
                maxWidth: '',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer',
                        itemId: 'spacer1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'vbox_Container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                itemId: 'name_Field',
                                minHeight: '',
                                label: 'Name'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datepicker'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer',
                        itemId: 'spacer2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'spacer',
                itemId: 'spacer3',
                maxHeight: 5,
                minHeight: 5
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                itemId: 'buttons_Container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer',
                        itemId: 'spacer1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId: 'delete_Button',
                        ui: 'decline-round',
                        text: 'Delete'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer',
                        itemId: 'spacer'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId: 'save_Button',
                        ui: 'confirm-round',
                        text: 'Save'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'spacer',
                        itemId: 'spacer2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

With containers width set at 100%, my field are still extending on 2 lines..?
[image: 100%container]

Still need help here

Comment: Try setting the width of your container to 100% and see what happens.

Comment: Updated with the container to 100%, didnt work out

Comment: Can you put it into fiddle so we can play with it and see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of behaviour happens if your container is set to hbox or vbox, that some item inside of it have flex values and other do not.

The mixing of having flex and not having it in the same container seems to crash sometimes.